# VBS error: Object required

Tags: windows, vbscript

I have no experience with VBS at all and am trying to create a VBS file that flips the screen, from some searches I got this:

```
a.SendKeys("^{DOWN}")
```

I know 'a' will not work as an object in this case but what do I need to put in there to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may know that the key combination for your task is (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>down arrow</kbd>),
so you need to send those keys to the shell:

```
set a=createobject("wscript.shell")
a.sendkeys("%^{down}")
```

% ⇒ <kbd>alt</kbd>

^ ⇒ <kbd>ctrl</kbd>

{down} ⇒ <kbd>down arrow</kbd>

[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)